# Select, hyperlinks and imported templates not working after file restructuring?

Tags: html, jquery, drop-down-menu, path, hyperlink

I am using jQuery to import universal template files into certain parts of my page. Everything was working perfectly until I organized my filing structure differently. Now along with the header, my SELECT dropdown isn't working, and half of my regular hyperlinks cannot be followed even though VSCode auto-filled them in so I know I have rewritten the new paths correctly.

Everything seems to be exactly where it should be in the code, yet random parts don't appear or cannot be clicked anymore. I feel like I just turned months worth of work into shambles and I'm not sure how to fix it!

One of my biggest issues at this point is that I have never seen a good, in-depth explanation on file structuring and what is or isn't allowed.

Are there rules in place that don't allow a reference to certain types of files unless they are stored in the same folder?

Comment: What you looking for and should read into is the difference between **absolute paths**, **root-relative paths**, and **file-relative paths**. `./` selects the path from the `root`. `../` goes one folder down in the hierarchy (file-relative). For the format of the question, only write the necessary information. It is irrelevant if you're new to programming or using VSC. Then the question has nothing to do with `CSS`.  Then it is important to state the correct language in your case `jQuery` which differs from vanilla JS.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
If you share your code (done!), your current file structure, and any error messages or symptoms, you'll increase your chance of getting help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check all your z-index settings on hyperlinks, select functions or other areas in which you are able to view but seem unable to click.

I discovered that somewhere in the process of making changes on my project, I accidentally managed to get an invisible element overlaying certain features, inhibiting me from activating them, even though I could see them.

ALSO NOTE: just because you have a z-index set to a high level on an element it still might be being overrode by its parent element's z-index being undeclared, or at some lower setting.